# Product Not Displaying in Category List With PrestaShop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, product, categories, prestashop-1.7

I'm currently working on a PrestaShop site with the latest version (1.7) I'm facing a peculiar problem when listing products in categories. Indeed when I create a new product from the back office, I cannot view this product in the list of products by categories. However, I can access the detailed product page.

For the creation, I specify all possible parameters (price, description, reference, quantity, cover image, supplier, brand, etc.). I define the product as active. I assign the same category as an example product.

So I created a product "Test" that belongs to the category “Home -> Women -> Tops-> Blouses” based on the product example" Blouse ":

Result: The category "Blouse" shows me the product "Blouse" and not the product "Test."

I emptied the cache (why not?), re-indexed all the products (I don’t know why),  put back the default theme, compared the entries "Blouse" and "Test" directly in the database. Still nothing, I cannot find a difference between the two products that will justify that one is displayed and the other is not.

I also tried to change the product "Blouse" category to put it in another category available at Prestashop installation (Home -> Women -> Dresses -> Casual Dress). It does not work either.

I work on localhost, but I encounter the same problem on the beta version that is online.

Comment: Have you set the product to online? (Large radio button on the lower left side in the "action bar" thing at the bottom). I know you said you defined it as active, just trying to rule out the simple things first :)

Comment: Did you ever find out what the issue was? I am experiencing the same thing

Comment: Check in International > Localisation if you are using Geolocation and specifically if you are hiding catalog items for specific country's.